# Bayesian Network Probability

Tags: probability, bayesian-network, artificial-intelligence

[image]

Question # 1: On the network which I posted above, I am having trouble determining what the probability of:

P(A,F)

is and how it is derived?

My thinking was that if you have this event (A) that is true, has occured, and this other event (F) that is the child of event (A). In this case the probability of event (F) happening is heavily dependent on whether or not event (A) has occured. Therefore, if both occur then you can find the probability of both happening by multiplying their truth values:

P(A) * P(F|A) = 0.8 * 0.8 = 0.64 --> 64%

Question # 2: Similiar to the question above how can I find the probability of:

P(M, not(C) | H)

is and how it is derived?

I did some additional research and came to the conclusion that P(M, not(C) | H)

translates into P(M | not(C), H) * P(not(C) | H).

So in english, the probability of the event (M) occuring given that event (C) did not occur, is false and the event (H) occured multiplied by the probability of event (C) not occuring, is false, given that event (H) occured.

Thus, the total probability of the first operand:
P(M | not(C), H) = .04 --> 4%

From what I gathered is we are trying to find the probability of event (M) occuring given that event (C) did not occur and event (H) occured. Therefore, I multiplied .4, which is the probability of event (C) not occuring by the probability of event (H) occuring given the event (C) did not occur, which is .1.

.4 * .1 == .04 --> 4%

Thus, the probability of the second operand:

P(not(C) | H) can be expanded by Bayes Theorem =

(P(H | not(C)) * P(not(C)) / P(H))

(.1 * .4) / .7 = .05714 --> 5.714%

I got the .7 from the probability of event (H) happening regardless of the dependence on event (C) being true or false.

In conclusion,

.04 * .05714 = 2.2857*10^3 --> .002857 --> 0.2857 % (Less than 1 %)

Just need some clarification if both of these are correct, but more importantly if my logic of each problem is heading down the right road.

Comment: This is my first post, so if I messed up on formatting please feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: I've added the image in for you - for how to format your post better, take a look at [this mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: On the note of your question - you're right about the first one and wrong about the second - look up Bayes' theorem and the definition of conditional probability

Comment: Thanks for the link to formatting posts, appreciate you editing it. Will do!

Comment: Great first question on the site, by the way! Welcome :)

Comment: @B.Mehta Hey I did some additional research and think I have the correct answer now or at least my logic is somewhat more in line.